# How to check if there is no specific character left

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a JavaScript game of Hangman (JavaScript only NO jQuery whatsoever) this is my code to replace all unguessed letters with an '_'

```
function partialWords(random_word, letters) {
    var returnLetter = "";
    for (i = 0; i < random_word.length; i++) {
        if (letters.indexOf(random_word[i]) !== -1) {
            returnLetter = returnLetter + random_word[i];
        } else {
            returnLetter = returnLetter + ' _ ';
        }
    }
    return returnLetter;
}
```

I was just wondering if anyone would be able to help me with figuring out how to check if there are no more '_' left, thanks in advance!

Comment: What variable represents the one in which the `_` would appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method for a String Object too

```
if(returnLetter.indexOf('_') == -1) {

}
```

You can also hold missed letters in a separate Array

```
function partialWords(random_word, letters) {
    var returnLetter = "";
    var missedLetters = [];
    for (i = 0; i < random_word.length; i++) {
        if (letters.indexOf(random_word[i]) !== -1) {
            returnLetter = returnLetter + random_word[i];
        } else {
            returnLetter = returnLetter + ' _ ';
            missedLetters.push(random_word[i]);
        }
    }

    if(missedLetters.length > 0) {
        // do something
        // send missed letters
        return missedLetters.join(', ');
    }
    return returnLetter;
}
```

Comment: thank you! I like the idea of storing it in an array, cheers man

Answer (score 2):

To find out if there are *any* `_` in a given string:

```
if (stringVariableToCheck.indexOf('_') !== -1) {
    // there's at least one '_' in the string
}
```

To find out *how many* `_` there are in that string:

```
var numOfUnderScores = stringVariableToCheck.replace(/[^_]/g,'').length;
```

A somewhat contrived [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yHRZp/) (the demo does require an up-to-date browser, though).